# Extract text fields from xml/xslt to html or any text file?

Tags: xml, xslt

im trying my hand at solving an actual problem, it seems to be not so complicated but im really struggling. this is an xml file exported from final cut pro 10. it contains subtitles
Edit!!( I got it to work, it works fine but it outputs the text in one continuous line with dashes in between how can i make it on a new line?)

#

This is line 1
And this is line 2 (all middle centered)

This is line 1
This is line 2 - all in italics

This is line 1
This is line 2 all in bold

- This is double speak 1
- This is double speak 2 all left-aligned

Custom title line 1
Custom line 2

Middle generator
Line 1 plus enter

Middle generator line 2
plus entered line 2

#

And the code looks like this..................( only the first 30 lines are relevant )

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" version="2.0" href="filename.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE fcpxml>

<fcpxml version="1.7">
    <resources>
        <format id="r1" name="FFVideoFormatDV720x576i50" frameDuration="200/5000s" fieldOrder="lower first" width="720" height="576" paspH="59" paspV="54" colorSpace="5-1-6 (Rec. 601 (PAL))"/>
        <effect id="r2" name="Basic Title" uid=".../Titles.localized/Bumper:Opener.localized/Basic Title.localized/Basic Title.moti"/>
        <effect id="r3" name="Custom" uid=".../Titles.localized/Build In:Out.localized/Custom.localized/Custom.moti"/>
        <effect id="r4" name="Middle" uid=".../Titles.localized/Lower Thirds.localized/Middle.localized/Middle.moti"/>
    </resources>
    <library location="file:///Users/leonore/Movies/FCP%20X%20test.fcpbundle/">
        <event name="Captions test" uid="2215EAC2-906E-4187-A312-C5EDCF309AC7">
            <project name="Untitled Project" uid="95CC4E58-3904-4445-9AC0-937615D6F9C5" modDate="2018-04-02 12:16:13 +0200">
                <sequence duration="266400/5000s" format="r1" tcStart="0s" tcFormat="NDF" audioLayout="stereo" audioRate="48k">
                    <spine>
                        <title name="This is line 1 - Basic Title" offset="0s" ref="r2" duration="50200/5000s" start="3600s">
                            <param name="Flatten" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/351" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/354/3000025419/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/354/999169573/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <text>
                                <text-style ref="ts1">This is line 1
And this is line 2 (all middle centered)</text-style>
                            </text>
                            <text-style-def id="ts1">
                                <text-style font="Helvetica" fontSize="63" fontFace="Regular" fontColor="1 0.999974 0.999991 1" alignment="center"/>
                            </text-style-def>
                        </title>
                        <title name="This is line 1 - Basic Title" offset="50200/5000s" ref="r2" duration="50200/5000s" start="3600s">
                            <param name="Flatten" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/351" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/354/3000025501/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/354/999169573/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Font" key="9999/999166631/999166633/5/999166635/83" value="93 1"/>
                            <text>
                                <text-style ref="ts2">This is line 1
This is line 2 - all in italics</text-style>
                            </text>
                            <text-style-def id="ts2">
                                <text-style font="Helvetica" fontSize="63" fontFace="Oblique" fontColor="1 0.999974 0.999991 1" italic="1" alignment="center"/>
                            </text-style-def>
                        </title>
                        <title name="This is line 1 - Basic Title" offset="100400/5000s" ref="r2" duration="50200/5000s" start="3600s">
                            <param name="Flatten" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/351" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/354/3000025618/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/354/999169573/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <text>
                                <text-style ref="ts3">This is line 1
This is line 2 all in bold</text-style>
                            </text>
                            <text-style-def id="ts3">
                                <text-style font="Helvetica" fontSize="63" fontColor="1 0.999974 0.999991 1" bold="1" alignment="center"/>
                            </text-style-def>
                        </title>
                        <title name="- This is double speak 1 - Basic Title" offset="150600/5000s" ref="r2" duration="50200/5000s" start="3600s">
                            <param name="Position" key="9999/999166631/999166633/1/100/101" value="-520.415 -6.668e-12"/>
                            <param name="Flatten" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/351" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/354/3000025751/401" value="0 (Left)"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/999166631/999166633/2/354/999169573/401" value="0 (Left)"/>
                            <text>
                                <text-style ref="ts4">- This is double speak 1
- This is double speak 2 all left-aligned</text-style>
                            </text>
                            <text-style-def id="ts4">
                                <text-style font="Helvetica" fontSize="63" fontFace="Regular" fontColor="1 0.999974 0.999991 1"/>
                            </text-style-def>
                        </title>
                        <title name="Custom title line 1 - Custom" offset="200800/5000s" ref="r3" duration="25200/5000s" start="3600s">
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10199/10201/2/354/1002961760/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10199/10201/2/354/3001205098/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Out Sequencing" key="9999/10199/10201/4/10233/201/202" value="0 (To)"/>
                            <text>
                                <text-style ref="ts5">Custom title line 1
Custom line 2</text-style>
                            </text>
                            <text-style-def id="ts5">
                                <text-style font="Helvetica" fontSize="72" fontFace="Regular" fontColor="1 0.999974 0.999991 1" alignment="center"/>
                            </text-style-def>
                        </title>
                        <title name="Middle generator - Middle" offset="226000/5000s" ref="r4" duration="20200/5000s" start="3600s">
                            <param name="Position" key="9999/10393/10394/1/100/101" value="2.39185 44.6384"/>
                            <param name="Inside Path" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/332" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Shape Source" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/339" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Phase" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/346" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Attach To Shape" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/348" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Damping" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/349" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Align To Text" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/353" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Editable in FCP" key="9999/10393/10394/2/350" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Flatten" key="9999/10393/10394/2/351" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10393/10394/2/354/1156459982/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10393/10394/2/354/3001205313/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Opacity" key="9999/10393/10394/2/366" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Position" key="9999/10393/10410/1/100/101" value="0.0657212 -86.9112"/>
                            <param name="Shape Source" key="9999/10393/10410/2/329/339" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Editable in FCP" key="9999/10393/10410/2/350" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10393/10410/2/354/1156460000/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <text>
                                <text-style ref="ts6">Middle generator
Line 1 plus enter</text-style>
                            </text>
                            <text/>
                            <text-style-def id="ts6">
                                <text-style font="Gill Sans" fontSize="94" fontFace="Regular" fontColor="1 0.999974 0.999991 1" strokeColor="0 0 0 1" strokeWidth="4" shadowColor="0 0 0 0.75" shadowOffset="5 281.05" shadowBlurRadius="3.08901" alignment="center"/>
                            </text-style-def>
                        </title>
                        <title name="Middle" offset="246200/5000s" ref="r4" duration="20200/5000s" start="3600s">
                            <param name="Position" key="9999/10393/10394/1/100/101" value="2.39185 -15.8748"/>
                            <param name="Inside Path" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/332" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Shape Source" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/339" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Phase" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/346" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Attach To Shape" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/348" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Damping" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/349" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Align To Text" key="9999/10393/10394/2/329/353" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Editable in FCP" key="9999/10393/10394/2/350" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Flatten" key="9999/10393/10394/2/351" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10393/10394/2/354/1156459982/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Opacity" key="9999/10393/10394/2/366" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Position" key="9999/10393/10410/1/100/101" value="31.2122 1.02423"/>
                            <param name="Shape Source" key="9999/10393/10410/2/329/339" value="0"/>
                            <param name="Editable in FCP" key="9999/10393/10410/2/350" value="1"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10393/10410/2/354/1156460000/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10393/10410/2/354/3001205753/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <param name="Alignment" key="9999/10393/10410/2/354/3001205946/401" value="1 (Center)"/>
                            <text/>
                            <text>
                                <text-style ref="ts7">Middle generator line 1
plus entered line 2
</text-style>
                            </text>
                            <text-style-def id="ts7">
                                <text-style font="Gill Sans" fontSize="56" fontColor="1 0.999974 0.999991 1" bold="1" strokeColor="0 0 0 1" strokeWidth="4" shadowColor="0 0 0 0.6728" shadowOffset="3 315" alignment="center"/>
                            </text-style-def>
                        </title>
                    </spine>
                </sequence>
            </project>
        </event>
        <smart-collection name="Projects" match="all">
            <match-clip rule="is" type="project"/>
        </smart-collection>
        <smart-collection name="All Video" match="any">
            <match-media rule="is" type="videoOnly"/>
            <match-media rule="is" type="videoWithAudio"/>
        </smart-collection>
        <smart-collection name="Audio Only" match="all">
            <match-media rule="is" type="audioOnly"/>
        </smart-collection>
        <smart-collection name="Stills" match="all">
            <match-media rule="is" type="stills"/>
        </smart-collection>
        <smart-collection name="Favorites" match="all">
            <match-ratings value="favorites"/>
        </smart-collection>
    </library>
</fcpxml>
```

Now in this size its quite easy to just copy it out but obviously a program would be cooler, and this is what i have tried but i cant get it to work.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/fcpxml">
 <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <xsl:for-each select="library/event/project/sequence/spine/title/text">
    <h1>
     <xsl:value-of select="text-style" />
    </h1>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
 </html>



</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At this point it doest even reference the xsl file it just spits out the code as is when i open the xml file in IE, any pointers would be awesome thank you !!
(the whole point of this is to get the subtitles in a text file to spellcheck)

Comment: The output is not pretty, but the stylesheet works. If you only get plaintext output check the element `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"...` that it contains the right filename and also check the _Security Options_ of IE (often a problem).

Comment: In your XSLT, the `xsl:stylesheet` tag has two `version` attributes on it, one with value "1.0" and another with value "2.0". If your actual XSLT does have duplicate attributes then it would not be well-formed XML and so would not be loaded.